# Is there any mention about kali purush in Bhavishya malika?

Tags: puranas, kali-yuga, kali, kalki, kalki-purana

As kaliyug is of kali purush and kalki avatar is also for the end of kali purush and kaliyug so in bhavishya malika many predictions are there , i read the small version of bhavishya malika and i didn't found any mention about kali purush. So is there any mention about him? If not , why?